# Getting Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, material-design, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I was following a tutorial on implementing the navigationView from the design support library and I just can't get away from this error below. I've read the other solutions posted on this site, but none of them worked for me, please help.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActiviy.java

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Defining Variables
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.inbox:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inbox Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click
                case R.id.starred:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stared Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.sent_mail:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Send Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.drafts:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drafts Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.allmail:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Mail Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.trash:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trash Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.spam:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spam Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });

    // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mobinamanzai.projectalpha"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

EDIT:

Stack Trace
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 276203532 byte allocation with 12108696 free bytes and 174MB until OOM

EDIT 2: The problem seems to be in the header.xml

Comment: can you add more from your related stack trace

Comment: @Diyoda just edited it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all start from here,

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 276203532 byte allocation with 12108696 free bytes and 174MB until OOM at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609) at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
```

Because an image you are using for the header or as elements in your navigationdrawer has a higher resolution than the application allocated memory can handle. Reduce those images sizes and check. That will resolve the issue. If you add some more stack trace below, you can find what element exactly causing this problem.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be at any help.

Answer (score 6):

I got the inflater error for the Navigation view when switching to Android support library version 23.1.0, compile SDK version 23 and build tools version 23.0.2.

For me, it turned out to be a proguard issue.
Add the following line to your proguard configuration:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager { *; }
```

See [Android Open Source Project Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190250&q=label%3AType-Defect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Comment: Thanks man! I had the exact same issue and I don't know how would I solve it without your help :).

Comment: For me the Force close said Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager and thus the right fix for me

Comment: This actually solves a different problem but still nice to have here

Answer (score 1):

Yes, me too got same error.
If you look into error carefully u will find following line
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 276203532 byte allocation with 12108696 free bytes and 174MB until OOM

This is can resolved by minimizing resolution of images which are used for menu.